# Where goes WCF binding configuration?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I was checking out streaming in the Programming WCF Services book, and I spotted a line about configurating.

> You will need to configure the binding on the client or service side (or both) per required stream mode

So what is this? 
How I know where I should configure them?
And is this a common thing with WCF? 
Seems bit weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really basic example of how to configure a WCF service in your web/app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyServiceTypes.MyService" >
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:55555/MyService"
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          contract="MyServiceTypes.IMyService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

On the client side, you want to use the exact same endpoint settings, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:55555/MyService"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="MyServiceTypes.IMyService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

There are a ton of ways to customize the binding, etc. by adding bindingConfiguration sections, and stuff like that.  The binding configuration might be where you configure your streaming mode.

It's usually a best practice to put your contract interface; your service and client implementations; and your DataContract types (your data-transfer-objects) in a separate DLL if you can.  If you don't have control over the contract (e.g. you are accessing the service on a machine you don't control), an easy way to generate the client side code is to use "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio, or the svcutil tool.  I like svcutil better than Add Service Reference, because it gives you easier control over where the generated code ends up in your project.